# C# Bitwise XOR two very large hex numbers

Tags: c#, xor

I have two hex numbers, which, for the purposes of experimenting with OTP, I'm trying to XOR with C#. Unfortunately, both numbers are on the order of hundreds of digits - clearly far too large to store in an `int` or `long`. How do I store/XOR them? Right now, I'm storing as `BigInteger`s like so:

```
public static string XOR(string string_1, string string_2){
            BigInteger b1 = BigInteger.Parse(string_1, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
            BigInteger b2 = BigInteger.Parse(string_2, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
            BigInteger retVal = b1 ^ b2;
            return retVal.ToString("X");
        }
```

which isn't producing the expected result. Thanks!

EDIT:

Input:

```
string_1 = 32510bfbacfbb9befd54415da243e1695ecabd58c519cd4bd90f1fa6ea5ba47b01c909ba7696cf606ef40c04afe1ac0aa8148dd066592ded9f8774b529c7ea125d298e8883f5e9305f4b44f915cb2bd05af51373fd9b4af511039fa2d96f83414aaaf261bda2e97b170fb5cce2a53e675c154c0d9681596934777e2275b381ce2e40582afe67650b13e72287ff2270abcf73bb028932836fbdecfecee0a3b894473c1bbeb6b4913a536ce4f9b13f1efff71ea313c8661dd9a4ce
string_2 = 71946f9bbb2aeadec111841a81abc300ecaa01bd8069d5cc91005e9fe4aad6e04d513e96d99de2569bc5e50eeeca709b50a8a987f4264edb6896fb537d0a716132ddc938fb0f836480e06ed0fcd6e9759f40462f9cf57f4564186a2c1778f1543efa270bda5e933421cbe88a4a52222190f471e9bd15f652b653b7071aec59a2705081ffe72651d08f822c9ed6d76e48b63ab15d0208573a7eef027
```

Expected result (according to Python and [this online XOR calculator](https://xor.pw/?)):

```
32510bfbacfbb9befd54415da243e1695ecabd58c519cd4bd90f1fa6ea5b83624730b208d83b237176b5a41e13d1a2c0080f55d6fb05e4fd9a6e8aff84a9eec74ec0e3115dd0808c011baa15b2c29edad06d6c319976fc7c7eb6a8727e79906c96397dd14594a17511e2ba018c3267935877b5c2c1750f28b2d5bf55faa6c2218c30e58f17542717ad6f8622dd0069a4886d20d3d657a80a869c8f6025399f914f23e5ccd3a999c271a50994c7db959c5c0b73334d15ba3754e9
```

Comment: What is wrong with `byte[]` . BTW : `which isn't producing the expected result` What is your input? what is the expected output?

Comment: if ((b1 ^ b2) ^ b2) == b1 then it's working correctly

Comment: also add actual result please

Comment: @maxpovver: Strictly speaking, this is not correct. If `^` is implemented as doing nothing, your little expression will still evaluate to `true`. The same applies if `^` flips the bits of `b1` for which `b2` is 0 rather than 1, etc. There are lots of possible incorrect behaviours of `^` that your expression would not uncover.

Comment: Funny thing is that when a run OP's code with a slight change `BigInteger b1 = BigInteger.Parse(string_1, NumberStyles.HexNumber);` It get his expected result. So What is your question @KnightOfNi?

Comment: Have you tried a `ulong`?

Comment: @krillgar Come on, its only 8 bytes long. see the numbers in question.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I know, but if it fails it's the best way to make sure that it's broken

Comment: @maxpovver: Fair enough, but then you should have written "if `((b1 ^ b2) ^ b2) != b1` then it's working incorrectly".

Comment: @maxpower Based on that test, it's working correctly.

Comment: @KnightOfNi then the most possible reason is that it seriailizes/deserializes incorrectly

Comment: @Eser Just made the change you specified, I'm still not getting the output I think I should be getting

Comment: I am voting to close this issue as a "simple typo" or "can not be reproduced" since as Eser said it works as expected....

Comment: @L.B. As I said in my response to Eser's comment, that change is not producing the expected output when I run it...

Comment: You have a typo in your "Expected result" string in the 60th character.  You have "32510bfbacfbb9befd54415da243e1695ecabd58c519cd4bd90f1fa6ea5b8..." but it should be "32510bfbacfbb9befd54415da243e1695ecabd58c519cd4bd90f1fa6ea5ba..."  i.e. `a` instead of `8`.  I.e., you and @Eser have different expected results.  Eser's is copied correctly, yours is not.

Comment: @dbc I copied the expected answer from https://xor.pw/? as OP suggested.

Comment: @Eser - and you got it right.   OP's is wrong in the 60th character.

Answer (score 6):

Seems somebody doesn't want to believe.

```
var string_1 = "32510bfbacfbb9befd54415da243e1695ecabd58c519cd4bd90f1fa6ea5ba47b01c909ba7696cf606ef40c04afe1ac0aa8148dd066592ded9f8774b529c7ea125d298e8883f5e9305f4b44f915cb2bd05af51373fd9b4af511039fa2d96f83414aaaf261bda2e97b170fb5cce2a53e675c154c0d9681596934777e2275b381ce2e40582afe67650b13e72287ff2270abcf73bb028932836fbdecfecee0a3b894473c1bbeb6b4913a536ce4f9b13f1efff71ea313c8661dd9a4ce";
var string_2 = "71946f9bbb2aeadec111841a81abc300ecaa01bd8069d5cc91005e9fe4aad6e04d513e96d99de2569bc5e50eeeca709b50a8a987f4264edb6896fb537d0a716132ddc938fb0f836480e06ed0fcd6e9759f40462f9cf57f4564186a2c1778f1543efa270bda5e933421cbe88a4a52222190f471e9bd15f652b653b7071aec59a2705081ffe72651d08f822c9ed6d76e48b63ab15d0208573a7eef027";

//copied from https://xor.pw/?
string expectedResult = "32510bfbacfbb9befd54415da243e1695ecabd58c519cd4bd90f1fa6ea5ba3624730b208d83b237176b5a41e13d1a2c0080f55d6fb05e4fd9a6e8aff84a9eec74ec0e3115dd0808c011baa15b2c29edad06d6c319976fc7c7eb6a8727e79906c96397dd14594a17511e2ba018c3267935877b5c2c1750f28b2d5bf55faa6c2218c30e58f17542717ad6f8622dd0069a4886d20d3d657a80a869c8f6025399f914f23e5ccd3a999c271a50994c7db959c5c0b73334d15ba3754e9";

BigInteger b1 = BigInteger.Parse(string_1, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
BigInteger b2 = BigInteger.Parse(string_2, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
BigInteger retVal = b1 ^ b2;
var res = retVal.ToString("X").ToLower() == expectedResult;
```

Guess the `res` in answer. Of course **TRUE**. :)

Comment: I don't understand... This is working for me, but when I do the EXACT SAME THING as a method that gets sent two strings, it stops working... I literally copied and pasted this code, then made `string_1` and `string_2` parameters instead...